# Fetch source code of web page using java?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I have a URL like [this](https://www.google.com.tr/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiutz8c5SkNUkikuw6Mjg1cJ_1XWJ6tuAKi0uhzsdrLbNJe81pzBRqhUAkV0XkzHOUULPO98aWXObceNS-EWjuCIwAOD8M9nDdPcZKs1w05gSAa0XuIoJeCG12DTK7LpR-65PaSqU6mEqQs_1aHqZY5_1hyzgXzWAFKzhFFEWjMPYQUFg55Zf7Rui0S9mh6ae56WwPEGDvMwy6UExpsDYgB29gWf_1m7qHUKXmEwr57t3S5KEKKxLGzWohYqZ-8CrjgUkISXz-OC5sQnSd7wGOIBm2_1EkEXZydUprugFo6EIf3IUHJ79Y5Xt0CBhP84eXIJl8MRZFbQ6hLJ13e3gL986BgAJhkCeEMQmvhQGJgxR3nZlyVzkdSYuHvnXOzLE9czbRSnpswOM74I6EA5iI5W3yQjH0tluPTFN5_10uda6vTv5oBS_1-pDudS5ydBMpm08qKEwI7NTyoZwweuTdsvr7bsfkfPyhib8nZ775YDxNulXcq-z_1IppOnY7CED-bKfdHTr75uu8NdhQkImsj55fWp-tDqODaLVHtyqvayUCaY7PSqtDUSjouU9mCVdsvxFJvA4Lv4dsGNWe8A9eK_1eNbGIqKYYrgLjKaXlc1ZTjYiIm8MJqVp6LTp9zC8inWbIAeXrobk99N9d05lnJhXobeZZUl553ICCYh0dnJZpB4FuXXq-tgECH9ANR-NxhC4pG8_1vot-yDv2a1N8UuXkRe5PT2yz9bBOdMJ64mbjg1TQZzEFF00yRqULQjIMAEJJh3C3TOyi0mSvrTdCaKWIsC2CluU4hK-N-kiiKl7fxHFMpVodyjBdkjYww9eJUFN-qGXNugQ4foedanyvDpF1wwqDFTBAOxk7UBy7dUcZBw7M76q4yaiHVKf7qC_1fi8W3w_1SXJv_14j_1L-BZyYZaabTN1ph88OBXsVwdqyj4MPh7PsmQ--rvmeFYgIErgAWbZRw0TK4pLzJRrQdVMSQRfvA6I6_16Zc4pw6bIx6s2S69ptJZA6ZHvQroJaPnDYTMEbqqXEo1mEkgoVCiGt4y-hcqAQqPu5-hEXzM3PUGfqChE9OA2NAnLjYuu2aWAiEqEAMI_1G4yCsogPpmD2BGr-32Fdgtf70RDG3wCk8z7lAkaw18u0oE05aV8ZvoCuT1vU3TkfDmgoD_1q75j0A9bvhsYRwFm1TV6dS9hI2pDP968H7ii5XK1gQtxnxk&btnG=G%C3%B6rselle%20ara) and the following method

```
public static void saveContent( String webURL )throws Exception 
{

    URL website = new URL(webURL);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

However, When I want to print web content, it always fetches the source code of the main page(www.google.com).

How can I solve my problem ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should check your **webURL** parameter. May be when you call **saveContent** method passing value of **webURL**. The value of webURL already set "www.google.com".

Comment: As a general suggestion, I'd recommend that you take a look at Jsoup.

Comment: @soewin i checked webURL parameter and it is correct

Answer (score 1):

I copied yours code to netbeans and it seems to work correctly. I think the problem could lead on content in method argument "webURL". Try run your app on debug mode and look what you've got back there.

Comment: It has to be something with this URL because on my environment it works correctly...
I sent to this method statically main page from facebook and I've got a proper result...